# Arrray index need to find

Tags: php

I have following array in my code.

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [27411566] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1566
                    [english_name] => water
                    [arabic_name] => ???
                    [amount] => 4.5
                    [details] => Array
                        (
                            [sub_type] => ecom
                            [price] => 2.25
                            [quantity] => 2
                            [vendor_name] => Cure Pharmacy
                            [vendor_slug] => curepharmacy
                            [product_slug] => water
                            [category_name] => Cure Kits
                            [category_name_ar] => حقائب كيور
                            [image] => water.png
                            [is_not_online_pay] => 1
                            [variation_name] => 
                            [variation_value] => 
                            [variation_id] => 
                        )

                    [lasttime] => 1592404057
                    [itemid] => 27411566
                )

        )
)
```

I have 1596 product id and want to search "27411566" from array I used following code but not works.Can anyone help ?

```
$key = array_keys(1566, array_column($this->_items, 'id'));
```

Comment: i am not sure but you try `array_search` function for EX :- `$index = array_search("othername",array_column($my_array,"name"));
var_dump($my_array[$index]["id"]);`

Comment: $index = array_search($product['id'],array_column($this->_items,"id"));
                $keysArray = array_keys($this->_items);
                $findItemId = $keysArray[$index];

Comment: above code solved my issue.

Comment: Well, Sound Good...

Answer (score 0):

In Magento you can use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager for that.

```
$keyData = $this->arrayManager->get(
    $this->arrayManager->findPath(
       $keyToFind,
       $yourArrayHaystack
    )
);
```

Comment: I need in core PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I got

```
$index = array_search($product['id'],array_column($this->_items,"id")); 
$keysArray = array_keys($this->_items); 
$findItemId = $keysArray[$index];
```